# Filtering output on AWS State Machine

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, filter, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I'm currently stuck on how to filter the output from the previous step in my state machine.
Say the previous step in the state machine has an output of:

```
"input": {
"Configuration": [
  {
    "Hours billed": "40",
    "Billing class": "A", 
    "Taxonomy": "261QB0400X",
  },
  {
    "Hours billed": "40",
    "Billing class": "B",
    "Taxonomy": "261QB0400X", 
  },
  {
    "Hours billed": "20",
    "Billing class": "C", 
    "Taxonomy": "261QR1300X",
}
]}
```

Is there to filter that output? Say the filter is "Taxonomy": "261QB0400X", and we want the answer to look like this:

```
"Configuration": [
  {
    "Hours billed": "40"
    "Billing class": "A" 
    "Taxonomy": "261QB0400X",
  },
  {
    "Hours billed": "40",
    "Billing class": "B"
    "Taxonomy": "261QB0400X",
  }
]
```

I have tried using ResultSelector, Parameter, and OutputPath. But I haven't had much success.

I would love your insight on how I should write the next step/how to filter the data out by using a specific Taxonomy coming from the front-end.

Thank you